# Getting {xml_nodeset (0)} when using html_nodes from rvest package in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape headlines off a few news websites using the html_node function and the SelectorGadget but find that some do not work giving the result "{xml_nodeset (0)}". For example the below code gives such result:

```
url_cnn = 'https://edition.cnn.com/'
webpage_cnn = read_html(url_cnn)
headlines_html_cnn = html_nodes(webpage_cnn,'.cd__headline-text')
headlines_html_cnn
```

The ".cd__headline-text" I got using the SelectorGadget.

Other websites work such as:

```
url_cnbc = 'https://www.cnbc.com/world/?region=world'
webpage_cnbc = read_html(url_cnbc)
headlines_html_cnbc = html_nodes(webpage_cnbc,'.headline')
headlines_html_cnbc
```

Gives a full set of headlines. Any ideas why some websites return the "{xml_nodeset (0)}" result?

Comment: The nodes are apparently being loaded with Javascript (which rvest doesn't run), so you'd need a more heavy-duty tool like splashr or RSelenium. And careful, what you can scrape [within this site](https://edition.cnn.com/robots.txt) is limited, and [it's all copyrighted](https://edition.cnn.com/terms), so what you can do with it is limited.

Comment: @alistaire, gotcha - will look into the splashr &/or RSelenium. And thanks for the heads up re the copyright info.

Comment: You do not need a heavyweight dependency to get the data you need from this site. I really wish folks would stop defaulting to that "easy" answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please, please, *please* stop using Selector Gadget. I know Hadley swears by it but he's 100% wrong. What you see with Selector Gadget is what's been created in the DOM after javascript has been executed and other resources have been loaded asynchronously. Please use "View Source". That's what you get when you use `read_html()`.

Having said that, I'm impressed CNN is as generous as they are (you def can scrape this page) and the content is most certainly on that page, just not rendered (which is likely even better):

[image]

Now, that's *javascript*, not *JSON* so we'll need some help from the `V8` package:

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)

ctx <- v8()

# get the page source
pg <- read_html("https://edition.cnn.com/")

# find the node with the data in a <script> tag
html_node(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'var CNN = CNN || {};CNN.isWebview')]") %>% 
  html_text() %>%  # get the plaintext
  ctx$eval() # sent it to V8 to execute it

cnn <- ctx$get("CNN") # get the data ^^ just created
```

After exploring the `cnn` object:

```
str(cnn[["contentModel"]][["siblings"]][["articleList"]], 1)
## 'data.frame': 55 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ uri        : chr  "/2018/11/16/politics/cia-assessment-khashoggi-assassination-saudi-arabia/index.html" "/2018/11/16/politics/hunt-crown-prince-saudi-un-resolution/index.html" "/2018/11/15/politics/us-khashoggi-sanctions/index.html" "/2018/11/15/middleeast/jamal-khashoggi-saudi-prosecutor-death-penalty-intl/index.html" ...
##  $ headline   : chr  "<strong>CIA determines Saudi Crown Prince personally ordered journalist's death, senior US official says</strong>" "Saudi crown prince's 'fit' over UN resolution" "US issues sanctions on 17 Saudis over Khashoggi murder" "Saudi prosecutor seeks death penalty for Khashoggi killers" ...
##  $ thumbnail  : chr  "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/181025083025-prince-mohammed-bin-salman-small-11.jpg" "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/181025083025-prince-mohammed-bin-salman-small-11.jpg" "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/181025171830-jamal-khashoggi-small-11.jpg" "//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/181025171830-jamal-khashoggi-small-11.jpg" ...
##  $ duration   : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
##  $ description: chr  "The CIA has determined that Saudi Crown Prince Mohammed bin Salman personally ordered the killing of journalist"| __truncated__ "Multiple sources tell CNN that a much-anticipated United Nations Security Council resolution calling for a cess"| __truncated__ "The Trump administration on Thursday imposed penalties on 17 individuals over their alleged roles in the <a hre"| __truncated__ "Saudi prosecutors said Thursday they would seek the death penalty for five people allegedly involved in the mur"| __truncated__ ...
##  $ layout     : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
##  $ iconType   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```